# Smart Keyboard draining 2016 iPad Pro battery

Tags: ipad, smart-keyboard

My Smart Keyboard Is draining my 2016 iPad Pro battery. Apple Support cannot help. Just opened a case number for me without solving my issue.

[image: message while Smart Keyboard is Connected]

Smart Connector is clean (without any debris or cracks or nicks) and it attaches very strong with its magnet. Has anybody experienced this problem and had it resolved, and if so, what fixed the problem?

Apple Support cannot help. Just opened a case number for me without solving my issue.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: What to do. No Apple store at Greece.

Comment: what do you mean and how do you know it is draining the battery beyond designed ? Please explain what is your problem. What Smart keyboard ? Right now you have already 3 people asking to close your question, because it is unclear.

Comment: When Smart Keyboard is not connected to iPad,battery lasts for 1,5 days with normal iPad use. When Smart Keyboard is connected iPad battery lasts for 2-3 hrs (both cases with battery fully charged)

Comment: All i want to know is if this is a software ios12 problem regarding Smart Keyboard 2016 for iPad Pro 9,7 or is the end of life for my Keyboard (2yrs in use)..//

Comment: Apple offers 3 Years extended Warranty for your Keyboard. Get it replaced. https://9to5mac.com/2017/05/08/apple-smart-keyboard-ipad-pro-repair-program-sticking-keys-functional-issues/

Comment: I haven’t payed any extra money for getting an extended warranty when I bought the Keyboard..if that’s what you mean...i only payed 199 euros for the Keyboard.

Comment: Sorry. Didn’t see the link.  Thanks. I’ll try it with a premium reseller Here. 

Comment: What has the screenshot to do with the problem?

Comment: Whenever I attach the keyboard or during the use of it I get this pop up.

Comment: Since a week (after 2,5 years flawless use) I have the same problem. Out of nothing the battery gets drained from 100% to 0% in 6 hours in stand by. Went to the Apple Store and spoke to a genius without getting a solution except from a discount on a new iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apple offers extended three year repair program for iPad Pro Smart Keyboards w/ sticking keys & other ‘functional’ issues.](https://9to5mac.com/2017/05/08/apple-smart-keyboard-ipad-pro-repair-program-sticking-keys-functional-issues/)

Your Model Smart Keyboard for 9.7-inch iPad pro (Early 2016) is covered by this.

> Apple will also be issuing refunds to customers that previously paid
>   for a replacement for keyboards eligible under the new program.

Comment: Can u send me the Apple’s link of the warranty extension ...////????

Comment: when contacting apple support use the "case umber" they gave you

Comment: What Apple Support.....??? I’ve already contact them and they gave me no solution. Just a case number to call some country in the EU other than Greece because Apple greece number do not answer when I called them. I’ve been calling then 3days now at least 10 times a day.  So put yourself in my shoes having Apple support making a case number for you &telling you to call a EU support number other than your county’s to give you a solution for your case number. @@@@@ TRAGIC 

Comment: This is the US web site, change it to Greece https://getsupport.apple.com/

Comment: Did that. No result.

Comment: which option did you use ? send in, chat or call

Comment: Twitter   ..............